# Windows 10 Hello fingerprint issues

Tags: windows-10-v1511

Currently I have set up a windows 10 machine to our domain.

this machine is setup with 2 different set of domain id.

1 of which is an administrator account, and the other a normal user account.

I am able to add a fingerprint to the administrator account without any issues.

however when I add a fingerprint to the normal user account, no errors were given.

but I was not able to login to the normal user account using fingerprint

it gives a "couldn't recognize that fingerprint..." error

no issues for login into the Admini account using fingerprint though.

Comment: I suggest you setup the finger authentication again.  Use the normal means to authenticate the user.

Comment: Doesnt work as i have tried countless times. Even when its given elevated rights.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed similar issue by:
windows-x
find fingerprint reader and disable then enable
go to windows Hello where you set up a new fingerprint login - remove fingerprints if you have already saved
create new fingerprint - works for me